# Blackberry table View

Tags: java, blackberry

In my BlackBerry App, need to list items just like table view in IOS.anybody know which tool is better for this.is there a table view available in BB?

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
VKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

Go to the below Link and download zip file:

[TableLayoutManager.java](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-rich-UI-layout-with-TableLayoutManager/ta-p/445299)

According to that you can send values to that calss.

Answer (score 0):

Please try VerticalFieldManager Class. According to JDE 4.6.

```
net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager
```

Prasad.

Answer (score 0):

From Blackberry os 6.0 you can use [TableView Class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/table/TableView.html). Refer [How to use Table View layout](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2009/10/how-to-use-table-view-layout/).

For lower versions you should create a custom manager and override the sublayout method and inside it layout fields according to your needs.

see related stackoverflow links

- [BlackBerry Table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560925/black-berry-table-view)
- [blackberry tableview solution for jde 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881307/blackberry-tableview-solution-for-jde-4-5)